# SQL Server 2019 System.Data.SqlClient namespace query

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2019

I am using the .NET classes in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace on a SQL 2019 Enterprise Edition and have successfully run TSQL commands via the creation of a function in PowerShell.

```
function SqlQuery($server, $database, $query)
{
 $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"
 $connection.Open()
 $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
 $command.CommandText = $query
 $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
 $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
 $table.Load($result)
 $connection.Close()
 return $table
}

SqlQuery $Server $Database "SELECT * FROM Staff"
```

I have some quite large pieces of T-SQL code stored in discrete files that I would like to execute against this instance.  Is it possible to utilise the function to call a T-SQL script stored in a filesystem file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> possible to call a T-SQL script rather than include it in the main body of the PowerShell script

Of course.  Just read the file contents with [get-content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1) and pass that to the function:

```
function SqlQuery($server, $database, $query)
{
 $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
 $connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=True;"
 $connection.Open()
 $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
 $command.CommandText = $query
 $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
 $table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
 $table.Load($result)
 $connection.Close()
 return $table
}

$server = "localhost"
$database = "tempdb"
$sql = get-content "c:\test\foo.sql"

SqlQuery $Server $Database $sql
```

If the sql file contains multiple batches, you'll need to break it up yourself, or use use the [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet from the SqlServer module, which you can install with

```
install-module SqlServer
```